# Rails 3 Postgres working on Heroku but no longer locally PGError could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm using postgres 8.4 and Rails 3.0.9

A couple of days ago I was using this combo fine locally and on Heroku.  Today I load my Rails server locally and I get two new messages, a Deprecation Warning and a PGError.

The warning was that this:

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs
```

will no longer be supported in Rails 3.1.  I checked and I'm still using 3.0.9 just to be sure.

That was easily taken care of.  However the PGError is leaving me scratching my head.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "???" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "???" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried a bundle install and a bundle update.  The "is the server running on host '???'" seems to be strange but what does that mean?

Everything is working fine on Heroku.  I checked all my init and configure files and they all look the same as they were a few days ago.  Have any updates happened that might have caused this?

Comment: please check if postgresql is running executing command like `ps axu | grep postgres`

Comment: I tried your command and also ps ax | grep postgres and ps -ef | grep postgres in my git bash shell.  They all seemed to execute with no errors but there was no response message of any kind.  Do I need to look somewhere or does this mean everything is fine?

Comment: Looks like postgresql process is not running.  Probably, there are some logs in the database server directory to find problem.

Comment: Yeah, Postgresql wasn't running though I have no idea why.  I just restarted my computer and everything got up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if postgres database is running on specified host? Is database you're trying to connect works on localhost or on external sever?